# Leaflet map width in metres

Tags: dictionary, size, width, leaflet

I want to have a button that creates a circle on my leaflet map. 
The circle should be placed in the map Center and the diameter should be 75% of the current  displayed area width.
To get the `lat` and `lgn` of the Center was easy. But I don't know how the 75% of the map with in **metres** for the radius.

I tried the Method `getsize` but it returns the width in **px**. But I need this in **metres**.
Is there a plugin? Or is it possible to calculate it with the zoomlevel and the Pixel from getsize?

Comment: Can you explain more about what technology and software you are using. It  is not clear from the question, so this makes it impossible for anyone to answer you. Use the [edit] button to add those details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fetch the map bounds (which is a `LatLngBounds`), get the east (or west) longitude of those bounds, and use `L.LatLng.distanceTo` to get meters out of that, like:

```
var center = map.getCenter();
var eastBound = map.getBounds().getEast();
var centerEast = L.latLng(center.lat, eastBound);

var dist = center.distanceTo(centerEast);
var radius = dist * 0.75
```

Also remember that Leaflet has `L.Circle` which works in meters (or CRS units), and `L.CircleMarker` which works in pixels.

Comment: thanks a lot also for the usefull hint with Circle and CircleMarker.

Comment: L.latlng needs to be changed to L.latLng. Tried to edit but change was fewer than 6 characters